# Hide DIV when I click away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've read many SO answers on this but none of them is quite what I need. I have a `div` button which when clicked shows a `div` called `#settingswindow`. I would like to be able to close it when I click away.

The code below does that but the `#settingswindow` `div` also closes when I click on it, which is an undesirable effect.

```
// settings button
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#settings").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
  $("#settingswindow").toggle();
 });});
$(function(){
$(document).click(function(){
    $('#settingswindow').hide();
});
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line:

```
$("#settingswindow").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/N9cbk/

Comment: Would you mind adding a bit of an explanation to your code so that I can understand why are thing happening the way they are? Thanks

Comment: While this is the accepted answer, note that using stopPropagation() is not recommended. See here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-do-i-detect-a-click-outside-an-element?rq=1

Comment: @Kevin Using both the example in your linked css-tricks article or `stopPropagation` is a bad idea. The best way of achieving this effect is to make the container focusable and bind to the `blur` event instead. I will update this answer when I have time.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Not a good idea UX-wise. This means the modal will close when the user switches to another tab or window, or focuses on an input within the modal.

Comment: In addition, the 'click' event fires on mouse up, while the 'focusout' event triggers the instant you press mouse down. Normally, a button only performs an action if you press the mouse button down and then let go.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function for $('#settingswindow').click(), then use event.stopPropagation()
http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/ to stop event bubbling.

Comment: I do use event.stopPropagation() which does what it should and allows me to open the DIV instead of the body doing the .hide() effect. The problem is that when I click into the div... it hides and this being a setting window means that you cannot make any settings changes.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is you should set the tabindex attribute of the DIV to -1 
so that the focus events works for your div:

```
<div id="settingswindow" tabindex="-1"></div>
```

Set the focus, to the div, after displaying.
And then use the `focusin` or `focusout` jquery events to fix your problem.
like when focusout event happens, you can hide your div:

```
$('#settingswindow').focusout(function() {
    $('#settingswindow').hide();
});
```

here is a working sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/XVTuL/

Comment: This Plunker demonstrates the use of event.stopProgagation(): http://plnkr.co/edit/yvm0MEL9T56PipRk8W0J?p=preview

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. Any chance you could show it in a small jsfiddle snipet. Thanks again for the effort.